# Game of life, o que está errado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Estou treinando Python e recentemente estive tentando recriar o famoso "Game Of Life", consegui evitar falhas no código mas ele ainda nao está se comportando corretamente.
O programa era para se comportar dessa forma:
https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/
Note que o game ainda está sendo executado pela janela do console e é melhor visualizado pelo console padrão e ainda não implementei funções de edição por isso a grade é gerada aleatoriamente.
https://github.com/jeacom25b/python-game-of-life

```
def genhash(sizex=10, sizey=10):
    hash = {}
    hash["sizex"] = sizex
    hash["sizey"] = sizey

    for x in range(sizex):
        for y in range(sizey):
            hash[(x, y,)] = 0
    return hash


def hashprint(h, char0="0", char1="1"):
    if "sizex" in list(h.keys()) and "sizey" in list(h.keys()):

        x = h["sizex"]
        y = h["sizey"]
        p = ""

        for xx in range(x):
            for yy in range(y):

                p = p + (str(h[(xx, yy)]))
            p = p + ("\n")
        return p.replace("0", char0).replace("1", char1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("the argument is not a spatial hash")


def randomhash(h, rate):
    if "sizex" in list(h.keys()) and "sizey" in list(h.keys()):
        from random import random

        x = h["sizex"]
        y = h["sizey"]
        newh = {}
        newh["sizex"] = x
        newh["sizey"] = y

        for x1 in range(x):
            for y1 in range(y):

                r = random()
                v = 0
                if r < rate:
                    v = 1
                else:
                    v = 0
                newh[(x1, y1)] = v

        return newh
    else:
        raise ValueError("the argument is not a spatial hash")


def convolute(h, r="b3s23"):
    if "sizex" in list(h.keys()) and "sizey" in list(h.keys()):

        # rules
        rb = r.find("b")
        rs = r.find("s")

        b = [int(rule) for rule in r[rb + 1:rs]]
        s = [int(rule) for rule in r[rs + 1:]]

        # x,y !!
        x = h["sizex"]
        y = h["sizey"]

        for xxx in range(x):

            # torus wrapping
            xp1 = xxx + 1
            xm1 = xxx - 1

            if xp1 > x - 1:
                xp1 -= x

            if xm1 < 0:
                xm1 += x

            for yyy in range(y):

                # torus wrapping
                yp1 = yyy + 1
                ym1 = yyy - 1

                if yp1 > y - 1:
                    yp1 -= y

                if ym1 < 0:
                    ym1 += y

                # compute sum of neighbor cells
                sum = (h[(xm1, yp1)] +
                       h[(xxx, yp1)] +
                       h[(xp1, yp1)] +
                       h[(xm1, yyy)] +
                       h[(xp1, yyy)] +
                       h[(xm1, ym1)] +
                       h[(xxx, ym1)] +
                       h[(xp1, ym1)])

                # apply rules
                if h[(xxx,yyy)] == 0:
                    if sum in b:
                        h[(xxx,yyy)] = 1
                else:
                    if sum not in s:
                        h[(xxx,yyy)] = 0


    else:
        raise ValueError("the argument is not a spatial hash")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    h = genhash(20, 40)
    h = randomhash(h, 0.2)

    import time


    while 1:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        convolute(h)
        print(hashprint(h, " ", "5"),"console preview")
```

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada  - mas a primeira impressão é "está maior do que precisa ser" - me lembro de ter feito uma implementação bem concisa em 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - 
A sua pergunta não está bem formulada no sentido de que não fala exatamente qual é o erro.

Como eu sou meio fã do *game of life*, persisti um pouco -  foi somente quando criei uma uma função que populava sua matriz com um "movedor" igual o do exemplo que você aponta - e aí de fato temos um comportamento distinto.

Então em vez do sua função `randomhash` por:

```
def moverhash(h):
    [h.__setitem__((x,y), 0) for x in range(h['sizex']) for y in range(h['sizey'])]
    h[10, 10] = 1
    h[10, 11] = 1
    h[10, 12] = 1
    h[9, 12] = 1
    h[8, 11] = 1
```

Isso desenha a forma específica que deveria ir "andando" para baixo. 
(E a parte disso, veja que você pode usar tuplas (no caso, pares) como índices de dicionário sem usar um par de parênteses dentro do colchete)

Além dessa função, coloquei uma pausa controlada entre as gerações - como o seu programa é de console, um simples `input()` dentro do `while`, ao final, permite que só passemos ao próximo quadro ao apertar `<enter>`

Mas de qualquer forma, aí fica fácil ver que está errado - e mais pouco de atenção percebemos o por que:
Você está atualizando cada célula da matriz enquanto faz a varredura - mas está consultando *a mesma* matriz que está alterando. Dessa forma, quando você chega na coluna (y + 1), as células que ele consulta por vizinha na coluna (y)  já estão com os valores da próxima geração.     (outro detalhe: seu "x" está na vertical, e seu "y" na horizontal, denotando colunas)

Ou seja: ao computar os vizinhos de cada célula, você conta metade da grade na geração anterior, e a outra metade das células já computadas para a próxima geração.

Isso se resolve facilmente alterando seu `convolute` para receber a grade antiga, criar e preencher uma nova, e devolver a nova, a cada interação:

```
def convolute(h, r="b3s23"):
    if "sizex" not in h or "sizey" not in h:
        raise ValueError("the argument is not a spatial hash")

    # rules
    rb = r.find("b")
    rs = r.find("s")

    b = [int(rule) for rule in r[rb + 1:rs]]
    s = [int(rule) for rule in r[rs + 1:]]

    new_grid = {}
    # x,y !!
    x = new_grid['sizex'] = h["sizex"]
    y = new_grid['sizey'] = h["sizey"]

    for xxx in range(x):

        # torus wrapping
        xp1 = xxx + 1
        xm1 = xxx - 1

        if xp1 > x - 1:
            xp1 -= x

        if xm1 < 0:
            xm1 += x

        for yyy in range(y):

            # torus wrapping
            yp1 = yyy + 1
            ym1 = yyy - 1

            if yp1 > y - 1:
                yp1 -= y

            if ym1 < 0:
                ym1 += y

            # compute sum of neighbor cells
            sum_ = sum((
                    h[xm1, yp1],
                    h[xxx, yp1],
                    h[xp1, yp1],
                    h[xm1, yyy],
                    h[xp1, yyy],
                    h[xm1, ym1],
                    h[xxx, ym1],
                    h[xp1, ym1]))

            # apply rules
            if not h[(xxx,yyy)]:
                new_grid[xxx,yyy] = int(sum_ in b)
            else:
                new_grid[xxx,yyy] = int(sum_ in s)
    return new_grid
```

E, obviamente, mudar a chamada da função:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    h = genhash(20, 40)
    #h = randomhash(h, 0.1)
    moverhash(h)

    while True:
        print(hashprint(h, " ", "5"),"console preview")
        h = convolute(h)
        input()
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu vou melhorar minhas perguntas, mas como pode ver, tenho dificuldade até para dar bons nomes as funções.

Comment: eu não me xtendi sobre isso - mas em geral você chama os limites máximos no x e y de largura e altura (letras w e d) e deixa x e y para as coordenadas em que está atuando. Ai não precisa de nomex como "xxx" e "yyy".

Comment: sim, é verdade, eu preciso desenvolver esse habito, fiz as correções e o código funcionou perfeitamente. agora o próximo passo é implementar um interface gráfica.